# why cant i find mkdir on git 2.7.0?

Tags: git

I am a new user and while running through the starter i simply typed in mkdir as instructed but received this:

```
zella@zella-PC MINGW64 /c/Users
$ mkdir
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.

zella@zella-PC MINGW64 /c/Users
$ ^C

zella@zella-PC MINGW64 /c/Users
$
```

kindly advice me on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: are you trying to do `mkdir foldername`?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I am actually trying to create new directories and simply practice copying contents from one to the other. Im learning the basics

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to make a folder, you need to pass a folder name as a parameter to **[`mkdir`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mkdir)**.

Second, you don't have to use git bash: as long as `C:\path\to\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\bin` (or `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`) is in your environment variable `PATH`, you can remain in a regular CMD session, and use `mkdir` as usual.

Third, if you want to initialize a new git repo, you don't even have to create a new folder:
[`git init aNewRepo`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) will do it for you.

```
cd C:\Users\MyLogin
git init aNewRepo
cd aNewRepo
# work...
git add .
git commit -m "My First Commit!"
```